# How to prevent closing QMessageBox after clicking a button

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt5

I have 3 buttons on QMessageBox added by QMessageBox::addButton() method. Is it possible to prevent closing the message box if a button has been clicked? By default every button closes the window, but I don't want to do it for one button.

Comment: You may will have to create your own message box using QDialog

Comment: I have already done, but I just wonder whether it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through the `addButton()` functions overloads, but there is no custom behavior for the buttons you add with this method. They will behave like the standard buttons on a messagebox should.

However if you want to create a fully customizable dialog, then your best option is to extend the `QDialog` class and use whatever controlls you like on it.

Answer (score 6):

One interesting way to approach it that worked for me is to completely disconnect the signals for the target button created, and then re-add the intended functionality. This won't work for everyone, especially if the button isn't created this way and/or you still want to close the dialog correctly. (There might be a way to add it back and/or simulate the behavior with `QDialog::accept`, `QDialog::reject`, `QDialog::done` - haven't tried yet.)

Example:

```
QMessageBox *msgBox = new QMessageBox(this);
QAbstractButton *doNotCloseButton = msgBox->addButton(tr("This button will not close anything"), QMessageBox::ActionRole);
// Disconnect all events - this will prevent the button from closing the dialog
doNotCloseButton->disconnect();
connect(doNotCloseButton, &QAbstractButton::clicked, this, [=](){ doNotCloseButton->setText("See? Still open!"); });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can get a pointer to the `QMessageBox` widget, you can try to install a `QObject::eventFilter` on it which filters the `QEvent::Close`.

Answer (score 3):

Just had the same problem but I wanted to add a checkbox and it kept closing the dialog on clicked even with the `ButtonRole` set to `QMessageBox::ActionRole` (tried others too). For this scenario I just called `blockSignals(true)` on the `QCheckBox` and now it allows check/uncheck behaviour without closing the dialog.  Luckily `QCheckBox` works fine without signals but assume you want a signal from your button.

They should likely add a new role that doesn't close the dialog as it's a pain to derive a class for simple customizations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Albert's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49745613/8786297), I found that this also possible in python:

```
messagebox = QMessageBox()
button = QPushButton("This button will not close anything")
messagebox.addButton(button, QMessageBox.ButtonRole.NoRole)
button.disconnect()
```